# MIDI controller and software integration

Tags: software, midi-controller-keyboard

Is there a way to know if [this app](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vmpk/) (and similar apps) would work with with [this MIDI controller](http://www.samsontech.com/samson/products/usb-midi/keyboard-controllers/carbon49/) (and in general any MIDI controller). Is there a specific way to tell? (not sure if it matters, but I use a Mac)

Comment: I wouldn't be an authority on this sort of issue but from my experience, most USB MIDI controllers are plug and play, ie, function without any sort of installation/drivers.  I am also a Mac user and have had a couple different controllers but they have all been M-Audio.  These functioned in both GarageBand and Logic Pro.  I could imagine some apps not being as good at handling all controllers but it seems unlikely that a newer app would have a hard time managing controllers.  In other words, you're probably all set but maybe try to reach out to the maker of the app or controller to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

contact the developer and ask.  in general midi devices have changed very little since the late 80s.  All are interchangeable.  The big question is does that midi device have a device driver for the operating system you have.

so do your homework - contact the developer; contact the device manufacturer (or just read the device manufacturer's manual which is undoubtedly available on their website)